# Toyota Vitz (Yaris) 1999–2005 broken side marker mystery

Tags: electrical, toyota, damage, yaris, vitz

Today I found my Toyota Vitz 2001 car like this:

[image: broken side marker]

The side marker was broken to pieces and I found it on top of the hood.

I initially thought that the connector was missing too (see reference image below):

[image: connector]

However, I tried turning on the indicator and I can see that the light is working, so it is probably there, and only the external marker was broken.

**Is there any way this could have happened accidentally, or have fallen off on its own?** Given that I found the side marker in pieces on the hood, the only explanation I can think of is someone doing this to deliberately damage my vehicle (nothing else was damaged though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible that the side marker cracked and fell off on its own.

You see how your headlight lens is so badly weathered that it is no longer transparent? This is caused by 20+ years of sunlight. The same sunlight can weaken and crack a side marker to the extent that it simply falls off the car at a random time.

It's possible that a kind stranger collected the pieces from the ground and placed them on your hood to alert you to the fact that the side marker is broken. Otherwise, you could get in the car and drive away without realizing.

Is it also possible that someone intentionally broke it and placed it on your hood to make sure you know that you were vandalized? Sure, anything is possible.

Look at the side marker on the other side. You may find that it is cracked and barely holding itself to the fender.